# Can webmatrix query an external odata web service like stackoverflow using razor

Tags: odata, webmatrix

i was hoping i could capture external web service just the way i interact with my database e.g

```
var data_websevice = Database.Open("http://www.stackoverflow.com/atom/tags");
```

is this a possibility?

I actually need to return a json data  to my client page. using the autocomplete jquery UI.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the Database helper for that. It's only intended for use with databases.

You can obtain data from an external resource by Uri using the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to request it, just like in any other ASP.NET application.